# Vue.js : Call a Method from another Component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

this is my HTML from **Component1**

```
 <component2></component2>
```

this is my `<script>` from **Component1**

```
export default {
 
  methods: {
    fetchData()
    {
    ...
    }
 }
}
```

and i wanna call the method `fetchData()` in **Component2**

my `<script>` from **component2**

```
 export default {
     ...
    }
```

i tried:  `this.$root.$refs.c1= this;` ...  `this.$root.$refs.c1.fetchData()`

i tried to set an event

nothing worked

Comment: I assume that **Component1** is the parent of **Component2**?

Comment: To which component *should* the method belong?  Maybe both components should import "fetch" as a utility.

Comment: @danh the fetchdata method is in component1 and i have a method in component2 which should call the fetchdata method in component1

Comment: @Tecto - I understand, but I'm challenging the assumption of the question that one component should have a method that both need.

Comment: @danh, okay lets explain it: the component1 is a table and the component2 is one row of the table, an in the row component i can edit the row and safe it and after that the fetchdata method of the table component should call, to refresh the whole table. so the row component is not possible to refresh the table with the method, it needs to call the fetchdata method from the table

Comment: In that case, the table is responsible for fetching data, and the row is responsible for emitting an event to let the table know to refresh the data. props/emit is sufficient for this, no need to reach into the parent component and access the method directly from the table row.

Comment: @Excalibaard okay okay sorry for the question but how can i emit the table component to refresh

Comment: The @Laerte answer demonstrates how a child can emit and how the parent can react.  I'd probably rename the emitted message to something like "row-saved" and have a similarly named method on the parent.  (Incidentally, this question seems to be unfairly downvoted without explanation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could call emit on Component2 and call fetchData when Component1 receives it:

```
<component2 @fetch="fetchData()"></component2>
```

And on Component2, you need to emit `fetch` at somepoint. For example:

```
export default {
    created() {
        this.$emit('fetch')
    }
}
```

Comment: and then? how i call the fetchdata method in component2?

Comment: You use Component2 to emit the `'fetch'` event, which triggers fetchData in Component1, essentially calling the method from Component2 but in a clean way instead of entangling the components together. If you need to use the results in Component2, you can pass them from Component1 to Component 2 with a prop.

Comment: @Excalibaard okay but i tried it exactly like laerte but it didnt work, fetchdata doesnt trigger

Comment: If you tried it exactly like he said, it should work. Maybe something is wrong with your fetchData method or a misspelled event name, you could update your question with the code you've tried so far (include what's actually in the methods themselves).

Comment: i add an console.log at the beginning of the method and it doesnt trigger

Comment: To clarify, given the OP's comments, some user action (like save) triggers the need for the parent to re-run fetch (not on create).

Comment: Then make sure your method and your listener are spelled correctly, and don't contain capital letters, https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html . Component 2 should have only `this.$emit('fetch')` somewhere where it should trigger the data to be refreshed (for example your saveRow method). Component1 should contain the fetchData method and render component2 in its template, as described in the answer. Edit queue is full, otherwise I'd adapt the example to your situation.

Comment: @Excalibaard and @danh already posted great explanations about my answer, but, just to add a little more info on it: the main idea is to send a message from comp2 to comp1, telling that you want to do something. This is made by `emit`. It is basically saying to comp1, that comp2 wants to fetch data. So, when comp1 receives the message `@fetch`, it may call something, which, in your case is `this.fetchData()`. Basically, comp2 will NOT call `fetchData()` directly, it will tell comp1 to call it instead. Hope this makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

Template in `Component2` should equal:

```
 <component2 ref="childComp"></component2>
```

Then your `fetchData` method in `Component1` could look like:

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    fetchData() {
      return this.$refs.childComp.fetchData();
    }
  }
}
```